# @Asyn annotation with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use @Async annotation provided by spring. Going through some of the blogs I found there are the following constraints for using it:

1. It must be applied to public methods only
2. Self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work

I have a method which is getting called from the same class which I want to mark @Async. Is there any way of achieving it from the same class?

Comment: how did you proceed?

Comment: Still looking for a solution. We are working on spring 4.2

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring v4.3+ you can use self injection, and call the method on the self injected reference.

So for example:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    private SomeClass selfInjected;

    public void someMethod() {
       selfInjected.someOtherMethod();
    }

    @Async 
    public void someOtherMethod(){
      ...;
    }
}
```

**Updated as OP is using version before 4.3:**

This will work for you.

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private SomeClass selfInjected;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        selfInjected = applicationContext.getBean(SomeClass.class);
    }
}
```

**Or**

The other option is to extract the method to separate class and autowire it. I would personally explore this option before doing the above method.

Comment: I extracted the method to a separate class and auto wired it. Tried with the self injection with application context but still the execution was done with the same thread.

Comment: Is it possible to share the code with `ApplciationContext`